# Content availability. Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an application where the user can add quotes.
I'm using Room for data storage.

I want to make it so that the user can add a quote and it would be visible to other users of the application.

Questions:
How can this be done correctly?
How to open access so that all users can see, not just you?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to multiple users on the same device or multiple users across multiple devices? The two tasks are quite different, though both can be solved by using a server with a DB to store the quotes and utilizing Room as a sort of local cache.

Comment: I want to implement registration. Then, so that the registered user can add content and this content can be selected by other users.
But I don’t know exactly how to implement it so that other users can see the content.

Comment: You still need to provide more clarification, are you talking different users on the same device (and if so, multiple users in the same system account, or different accounts (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user)) or different users across different devices. Are all users supposed to see all "posts" or only the ones from users they've "subscribed" to? Do you need to register to see the "posts"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.